# mvc.sitemap couldn't be found exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have installed MVCSitemapProvider, I need to make it scan assemble without using mvc.sitmap xml file. From [this article](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider) I have done that.

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile" value="false"/>
```

Then I deleted mvc.sitemap file, but I faced "mvc.sitemap couldn't be found" exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug. It has now been fixed in [v4.6.2](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.6.2).

Comment: Thank you for reply, but when I tried to install version from package manager I have not found error

Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC 4.6.2

Comment: If you haven't uninstalled the package, you need to run `Update-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5` or `Update-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4` depending on your MVC version. If you did uninstall the previous version, it would be `Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5` or `Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4`.